# Java Certificate chain validation -works fine for Self signed certificate and for entrust signed certificate it fails

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate

The method is going to get a certificate as input (certificate converted to byte[]) and it validates the requested certificate against cacerts, the app will be configured with the alias of the certificate to look into cacerts for verification.

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {

    byte[] in = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("request.crt"));
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
    Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is);
    is.close();
    X509Certificate requestCert = (X509Certificate)certificate;

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File("cacertspath"), "changeit".toCharArray());
    Certificate certFromTrustStore = (Certificate)keystore.getCertificate("certAliasAtServertruststore");
    certFromTrustStore.verify(requestCert.getPublicKey());      
}
```

Above piece works fine for self-signed certificate whereas for signed I get below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 512 but was expecting 256
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:212)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1416)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:790)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:390)
    at ValidateCertTest.main(ValidateCertTest.java:44)
```

====Edited==
My program tries to validate requested certificates chain is valid against a keystore.

Used CertPathValidator to validate certificate chain. Will below program can validate the requested certificate chain against keystore. Keystore is loaded with Root, Intermedia and child certificate?

public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException,
NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException,
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, CertPathBuilderException, CertPathValidatorException {

```
    byte[] in = Files
            .readAllBytes(Paths.get("request.crt"));
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
    List<X509Certificate> certificateToCheck = (List<X509Certificate>) certificateFactory.generateCertificates(is);
    is.close();
    final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(
            "verificationKeystore"),
            "keystorePass".toCharArray());
    for (X509Certificate requestCert : certificateToCheck) {
        System.out.println("Request Cert DN>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + requestCert.getSubjectDN().getName());

        final CertPathBuilder certPathBuilder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX");
        final X509CertSelector certSelector = new X509CertSelector();
        certSelector.setCertificate(requestCert);
        final CertPathParameters certPathParameters = new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustStore, certSelector);
        final CertPathBuilderResult certPathBuilderResult = certPathBuilder.build(certPathParameters);
        final CertPath certPath = certPathBuilderResult.getCertPath();

        final CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
        final PKIXParameters validationParameters = new PKIXParameters(trustStore);
        validationParameters.setRevocationEnabled(true); // if you want to check CRL
        final X509CertSelector keyUsageSelector = new X509CertSelector();
        keyUsageSelector.setKeyUsage(new boolean[] { true, false, true }); // to check digitalSignature and keyEncipherment bits
        validationParameters.setTargetCertConstraints(keyUsageSelector);
        final PKIXCertPathValidatorResult result = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult) certPathValidator
                .validate(certPath, validationParameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, this is NOT chain validation. This is about one-tenth to one-hundredth part of chain validation. You don't show data and your description isn't very clear, but it sounds like you have the same cert in 'cacertspath' as you want to verify, but that's wrong for a CA-issued cert -- the cert (and key) used to verify a CA-issued cert is the _CA's_ cert not the end-entity's. ...

Comment: ... And there won't be just one CA; for any publicly trusted CA today like Entrust your EE cert will be signed, and verified, by an intermediate (aka subordinate) CA, and _that_ CA _may_ be signed, and verified, by a root CA, or by another intermediate, and so on. See RFC 5280 section 6 for a basic, but not complete, description of what you need to do for chain validation. (It's 24 pages.)

Comment: Thanks  for the response @dave_thompson_085. I'm checking the other options to validate the chain. Can i use certPathValidator for the verification?